# AppleScript to massage URLs

Tags: applescript, text, services

I want to have a Services menu item that takes the selected text (a URL) and escapes the percent character and the `#` character:

1. Replace `%` with `\%`
2. Replace `#` with `\string#`

I copied and edited an exisiting script that does similar text manipulation.  This seems to work fine *except* when the URL contains a `&`.

I think this has something to do with needing to use `quoted form of` string, but I can't quite determine the correct place to specify that.

Sample Input:

```
http://books.google.com?xxx&xxx%22+xxx#v=onepage&q=%22Search%20String&f=false
```

Required Output

```
http://books.google.com?xxx&xxx\%22+xxx\string#v=onepage&q=\%22Search\%20String&f=false
```

### Code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set sanatizedURLString to ¬
    (do shell script ("echo " & input & "  | sed 's/%/\\\\%/g' | sed 's/#/\\\\string#/g' ;"))
return sanatizedURLString
end run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd *code* it:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set aURL to input as string
    set sanatizedURL to ¬
        do shell script "sed -e 's:%:\\\\%:g' -e 's:#:\\\\string#:g' <<< " & aURL's quoted form 
    return sanatizedURL
end run
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full *code*.</sup>

---

**Notes:**

`input` is a *list* e.g.:

```
{"http://books.google.com?xxx&xxx%22+xxx#v=onepage&q=%22Search%20String&f=false"}
```

`set aURL to input as string` makes it:

```
http://books.google.com?xxx&xxx%22+xxx#v=onepage&q=%22Search%20String&f=false
```

In the `do shell script` *command* `sed` only needs to be called once, not twice as in the original *code*. `sed` can take multiple *commands* by using the `-e` *option*, thus no need in this case to *pipe* the *output* of one `sed` *command* to another `sed` *command*.

It is not necessary to `echo` something to `sed` as it can process a *file* or a *here string*, thus the use of `<<<` in the `do shell script` *command*, followed by `& aURL's quoted form` which is e.g.:

```
'http://books.google.com?xxx&xxx%22+xxx#v=onepage&q=%22Search%20String&f=false'
```

By quoting the `value` of `aURL` it keeps the *shell* from processing any *shell special characters* in the *string*.

Thus, when run, the `do shell script` *command* looks like e.g.:

```
do shell script "sed -e 's:%:\\\\%:g' -e 's:#:\\\\string#:g' <<< 'http://books.google.com?xxx&xxx%22+xxx#v=onepage&q=%22Search%20String&f=false'"
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full *code*.</sup>

The use of `:` vs. `/` in the `sed` *command* is a personal preference in this case as it makes the *command* easier to read when having to make multiple escapes.

The use of `echo` in the original *code* flattens the *list* to a *string*, however I prefer to not use that method in order to make the `do shell script` *command* less complicated.